# How is the order of appended strings disabling scrolling in UITextView?

Tags: ios, uitextview

This is a very strange issue-- I have a number of UITextViews that I'm building by appending NSMutableAttributedString sections to one overarching NSMutableAttributedString, then setting my UITextView.text equal to that string. I've used this method without problems for multiple other TextViews and have not had any issues.

For the section I'm working on now (on reading brain MRIs), there are 5 strings I'm trying to append. When I have them appended in the order 1,2,3,4, the UITextView scrolls normally and displays all the information. When I add 5, it cuts off at the bottom and doesn't scroll. [image: TextView with number 5 added] When I reorder them as 5,2,3,4,1, the UITextView scrolls normally again. [image: TextView with the order changed] [image: Showing that scrolling works normally with a different order] When I change the text of the 5th string to "test test test test" it scrolls normally.

Is there something in the text of the 5th string that is somehow interfering with the scrolling capabilities of the UITextView? Thanks-- I'm totally at a loss here.

```
// Brain MRI

    //Intro
    NSMutableAttributedString * neuroMRI = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"High signal intensity = bright = hyperintense\nLow signal intensity = dark = hypointense\n\nThere are 4 types of images you need to know.\n\n"];
    [neuroMRI addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:noteFont range:NSMakeRange(0, neuroMRI.length)];

    //T1 weighted
    NSMutableAttributedString * neuroMRI1 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"T1 weighted:\nFluid = low signal intensity\n\n\u2022Fat = white\n\u2022White matter = gray\n\u2022Gray matter = darker gray\n\u2022Fluid = very dark gray\n\u2022Air = black\n\n\u2022Good for looking at brain tissue\n\u2022T1 weighted can have gadolinium added, which shows up bright and won’t enter normal brain tissue\n\u2022Gadolinium lights up pathology on T1 imaging\n\u2022This is called a contrast-enhancing lesion: Dark on T1, bright on T1 with gadolinium\n\u2022Contrast-enhancing lesions can be ring-enhancing or homogeneously enhancing\n\n"];
    [neuroMRI1 addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:noteFont range:NSMakeRange(0, neuroMRI1.length)];
    [neuroMRI1 addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:titleFont range:NSMakeRange(0, @"T1 Weighted:".length)];

    //T2 weighted
    NSMutableAttributedString * neuroMRI2 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"T2 weighted:\nFluid = high signal intensity\n\n\u2022Fluid = white\n\u2022Gray matter = light gray\n\u2022White matter = gray\n\u2022Fat = black\n\n\u2022Good for looking at CSF spaces\n\n"];
    [neuroMRI2 addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:noteFont range:NSMakeRange(0, neuroMRI2.length)];
    [neuroMRI2 addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:titleFont range:NSMakeRange(0, @"T2 Weighted:".length)];

    //Flair
    NSMutableAttributedString * neuroMRI3 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Flair:\n\u2022Looks like T2 with dark CSF\n\u2022Most sensitive for edema\n\u2022Good at seeing pathology\n\n"];
    [neuroMRI3 addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:noteFont range:NSMakeRange(0, neuroMRI3.length)];
    [neuroMRI3 addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:titleFont range:NSMakeRange(0, @"Flair:".length)];

    //Diffusion weighted
    NSMutableAttributedString * neuroMRI4 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Diffusion weighted:\n\u2022Used to visualize areas of ischemia (visible almost immediately)\n\u2022Stroke is light on diffusion-weighted imaging, dark on diffusion ADC map\n\n"];
    [neuroMRI4 addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:noteFont range:NSMakeRange(0, neuroMRI4.length)];
    [neuroMRI4 addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:titleFont range:NSMakeRange(0, @"diffusion Weighted:".length)];

    //Dating a stroke on MRI
    NSMutableAttributedString * neuroMRI5 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"How to date a stroke using T1 and T2:\n\n\u2022Hyperacute (< 24 hrs): T1 isointense, T2 hyperintense (due to intracellular oxyhemoglobin)\n\u2022Acute (1-3 days): T1 isointense, T2 hypointense (due to intracellular deoxyhemoglobin)\n\u2022Early subacute (3-7 days): T1 hyperintense, T2 hypointense (due to intracellular methemoglobin)\n\u2022Late subacute (7-28 days): T1 hyperintense, T2 hyperintense (due to extracellular methemoglobin)\n\u2022Chronic (> 28 days): T1 hypointense, T2 hypointense (due to hemosiderin)"];
    [neuroMRI5 addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:noteFont range:NSMakeRange(0, neuroMRI5.length)];
    [neuroMRI5 addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:titleFont range:NSMakeRange(0, @"How to date a stroke using T1 and T2:".length)];

    [neuroMRI appendAttributedString:neuroMRI1];
    [neuroMRI appendAttributedString:neuroMRI2];
    [neuroMRI appendAttributedString:neuroMRI3];
    [neuroMRI appendAttributedString:neuroMRI4];
    [neuroMRI appendAttributedString:neuroMRI5];

    neuroMRIText.attributedText = neuroMRI;
```

Comment: Your embedded images aren't showing up.

Comment: Thanks-- I fixed it

Comment: I just tried that with `UIFont *noteFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];` and `UIFont *titleFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0];` ... scrolling works just fine.

Comment: That's accurate for the fonts. I'm not sure what's going on-- maybe it's just my computer? I've tried restarting the computer and xcode and I'm still getting the same problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you see the same issue if you create a new project with pretty much *only* a `UITextView` with the code you present here? Also, the top image you show looks like the text view is not fully sized to the bottom of the screen/superview like it is in the other images... Do you see anything odd if you check hierarchy when it's in that state?

Comment: Nope, nothing strange coming up with the hierarchy that I can tell, but I don't get the issue when I do a separate project. I'll play around with it some more and see if I can figure it out.